# Expression type '(Bool, Error?) -> Void' is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift

I created an app using [this](https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/touch-id-tutorial-ios-tutorial-ios11) tutorial. But it doesn't works.
I wrote all like in the tutorial. But this code do not works. And it does not want to convert to Swift 4.
Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import LocalAuthentication

class ViewController: UIViewController {

func showAlertController(_ message: String) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func touchID(_ sender: Any) {

    let context = LAContext()
    var error: NSError?



    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
        let reason = "Authenticate with Touch ID"
        context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason, reply:
            {(succes, error) in
                if succes {
                    self.showAlertController("Touch ID Authentication Succeeded")
                }
                else {
                    self.showAlertController("Touch ID Authentication Failed")
                }
                } as! (Bool, Error?) -> Void)
    }

    else {
        showAlertController("Touch ID not available")
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

This is an error:

```
38:23 Expression type '(Bool, Error?) -> Void' is ambiguous without more context
```

and

```
38:23 Cast from '(_, _) -> ()' to unrelated type '(Bool, Error?) -> Void' always fails
```

Answer (score -2):

Expression type '(Bool, Error?) -> Void' is ambiguous without more context because always fails so just remove:

```
as! (Bool, Error?) -> Void
```

Which is extra as below:

```
if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
    let reason = "Authenticate with Touch ID"
    context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason, reply:
        {(succes, error) in
            if succes {
                self.showAlertController("Touch ID Authentication Succeeded")
            }
            else {
                self.showAlertController("Touch ID Authentication Failed")
            }
            } )
}
else {
    showAlertController("Touch ID not available")
}
```

Comment: In your answer, there was missing :reply that's why "yabashist" got extra error . and you asked him to make new question which is duplicate !